# Need to download Census 2010 population,aging and housing information at block group level

Tags: data

I would like to download 2010 census population,aging and housing information at blockgroup level.Such as Total population,age_5_9...,age_85_up,Household Count,Housing_units,SQML etc

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/downloading-us-census-data

Comment: Dig in... https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Use TIGER census data from the Census bureau. 
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

As for at the block group level, I think you will have to do some field calculations yourself based on what is in there but it should be simple enough (~10 minutes).